# How do I take in one input when I use cin for two inputs?

Tags: c++

So in most of the lines of input I have to take an integer, then space, then a string, like '3 kldj' or '5 sfA' but to indicate a stop I have to only take in the integer 0. Using cin >> intVar >> stringVar; it always keeps looking for the stringVar and doesn't accept just 0. How do I take in only N when the string is empty?

```
if (!(cin>>N>>input)) {
    break;
    cin.clear();
}
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work. This is inside a while loop so I use this to break out of it. N  is an integer and input is a string.

Comment: Do `cin>>N`, check if `N` is `0`, and only do `cin>>input` if it isn't.

Comment: Can you have a 0 on "regular" lines as well?

Comment: I'm surprised by the fact that you have something after the break. Off topic, but you do know that the cin.clear will never be called right?

Comment: `break` can't affect a previous statement, so will not prevent the `>>input` from waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP you should probably give up trying to this in one Input line. split it into two:

```
int N;
std::string input;

while (true) {
    std::cin >> N;
    if (N == 0) {
        break;
    }
    std::cin >> input;
}
```

This should work just fine. When the user Inputs `0` for `N` than the loop exits.
If you however have to do it one Input line you will have to go for the hard way.
Meaning using [`regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). It allows you to parse the input and always guarantee a certain behaviour.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility> //std::pair

int main() {
    const std::regex regex{ "^(?:([0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z]+))|0$" };
    std::smatch smatch;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> content;

    std::cout << "type in numbers + word (e.g. \"5 wasd\"). single \"0\" to exit.\n\n";

    std::string input;
    while (true) {
        bool match = false;
        while (!match) {
            std::getline(std::cin, input);
            match = std::regex_match(input, smatch, regex);
            if (!match) {
                std::cout << "> invalid input. try again\n";
            }
        }
        if (input == "0") {
            break;
        }
        auto number = std::stoi(smatch.str(1));
        auto word = smatch.str(2);
        content.push_back(std::make_pair(number, word));
    }

    std::cout << "\nyour input was:\n[";
    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < content.size(); ++i) {
        if (i) std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << '{' << content[i].first << ", " << content[i].second << '}';
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";
}
```

example run:

```
type in numbers + word (e.g. "5 wasd"). single "0" to exit.

5 asdf
12345 longer
hello
> invalid input. try again
5
> invalid input. try again
0

your input was:
[{5, asdf}, {12345, longer}]
```

explanation of the `^(?:([0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z]+))|0$`:

- 1 `"([0-9]+)"` - capture any (non zero) number of digits
- 2 `" "` - a single space
- 3 `"([a-zA-Z]+)"` - capture any (non zero) number of a-z or A-Z characters

the whole Thing is organized like `(?: /*…*/)|0` meaning *either* the string consisting of rules 1-3 *or* just one \"0\" matches the input. `^` and `$` indicate beginning and end of input. `?:` makes it able to group rules 1-3 without capturing it.

Comment: "It allows you to elegantly parse ..." -- that should be "elegantly and **expensively**". A regular expression is overkill for something as straightforward as this.

Comment: @PeteBecker i think the expensive argument is irrelevant since there's Input involved which is magnitudes of times more expensive, run time wise speaking. yes it is overkill and probably goes beyond OP's understandings but I don't see another way to make this ruling work unless OP gives up on inputting in one line and just uses two. Than it's really simple and probably can be solved within 4-5 lines or so.

Comment: It's expensive because parsing and applying regular expressions requires a substantial amount of library code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can also have zero at the beginning of a "non-terminating" line, turn the problem around from "read just a number if the number is not followed by a string" to "read a number and then read a string, but only if the number is not 0".

```
while (cin >> N && N != 0)
{
    if (cin >> input)
    {
        // Handle input
    }
}
```